# Calling Variable out of the switch case Java

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

I am writing a simple thermostat program in java. I have switch case in while loop. In the switch statement, the user chooses the option. I want to display the option at the last of the loop. Here, I want to display ttemp,tmode,tfan in GUI after the switch statement and while loop. It is showing error of cannot find symbol.

```
boolean run=true;

   String[] menuMain ={"Mode","Fan","Temp","PowerOff"};
   String[] menuMode ={"Cool","Heat","Off","Auto"};
   String[] menuFan ={"On","Off","Auto"};
   String[] menuTemp ={"Up","Down","C<>F"};

   String curtemp1= "Current Temperature: "+curTemp;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,curtemp1);
   while(run){


      int selMain =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Select Menu item","Menu",
      0,3,null,menuMain,menuMain[0]);

     String tmode;
     String tfan;
     double ttemp;

      switch(selMain){
         case 0:  //Mode
            int selMode=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Select a Mode",
            "Menu",0,1,null,menuMode,menuMode[3]);

            if (selMode==0)   {tmode="Cool";}
            if (selMode==1)   {tmode="Heat";}
            if (selMode==2)   {tmode="Off";}
            if (selMode==2)   {tmode="Auto";}

            break;
         case 1: //Fan
            int selFan=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Select Options",
            "Menu",0,1,null,menuFan,menuFan[2]);
            if (selFan==0)   {tfan="On";}
            if (selFan==1)   {tfan="Off";}
            if (selFan==2)   {tfan="Auto";}

            break;
         case 2:  //Temp
            int selTemp=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Select Options",
            "Menu",0,1,null,menuTemp,menuTemp[2]);

            if (selTemp==0)   {curTemp++;}
            if (selTemp==1)   {curTemp--;}
            //if (selTemp==2)   
            ttemp=curTemp;


            break;   
         default: //Off
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Power Off !");
            run=false;

         }  //end switch
         }  //end while loop
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ttemp,tmode,tfan);
         }
}
```

Comment: Note that it seems that your conditionals could be replaced by `tmode = menuMode[selMode]`. (Taking that up another level and using a `Map<String, List<String>> menuOptions` would probably allow you to eliminate all of your conditionals.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare these variables before while loop

```
boolean run=true;

   String[] menuMain ={"Mode","Fan","Temp","PowerOff"};
   String[] menuMode ={"Cool","Heat","Off","Auto"};
   String[] menuFan ={"On","Off","Auto"};
   String[] menuTemp ={"Up","Down","C<>F"};

   String curtemp1= "Current Temperature: "+curTemp;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,curtemp1);

   String tmode;
   String tfan;
   double ttemp;
   while(run){


      int selMain =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Select Menu item","Menu",
      0,3,null,menuMain,menuMain[0]);


      switch(selMain){
         case 0:  //Mode
            int selMode=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Select a Mode",
            "Menu",0,1,null,menuMode,menuMode[3]);

            if (selMode==0)   {tmode="Cool";}
            if (selMode==1)   {tmode="Heat";}
            if (selMode==2)   {tmode="Off";}
            if (selMode==2)   {tmode="Auto";}

            break;
         case 1: //Fan
            int selFan=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Select Options",
            "Menu",0,1,null,menuFan,menuFan[2]);
            if (selFan==0)   {tfan="On";}
            if (selFan==1)   {tfan="Off";}
            if (selFan==2)   {tfan="Auto";}

            break;
         case 2:  //Temp
            int selTemp=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Select Options",
            "Menu",0,1,null,menuTemp,menuTemp[2]);

            if (selTemp==0)   {curTemp++;}
            if (selTemp==1)   {curTemp--;}
            //if (selTemp==2)   
            ttemp=curTemp;


            break;   
         default: //Off
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Power Off !");
            run=false;

         }  //end switch
      }  //end while loop
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ttemp,tmode,tfan);
   }
}
```

Because this variables are visible only in the context where you declare it (in your example it was while loop. And outside this context, the variable becomes invisible